# Maven dependency pom files showing html instead of the correct pom file

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

[image: Error code]

This is the pom file that it generated:

[image]

This should be the pom file I think: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-enforcer-plugin/1.0/maven-enforcer-plugin-1.0.pom.
I have tried putting a mirror in my `settings.xml` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Please don't use images for errors and code. Just copy&paste them into the question. Furthermore, it is likely that you use a wrong repository address.

Comment: You have given the correct location in your post (link to https://repos...)  but the console output shows a different groupId which is cause of this problem. Your groupId is wrong...maybe more...furthermore I would ask why do you use such an ancient version of that plugin...Apart from that I strongly recommend to turn on the checksum policy in your `settings.xml` file (Details: https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/)